# document.add(table) is not finishing

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext7

I have wrote a PDF generator program which create a tabular report in PDF file. The version of my code which works, looks as follows:

```
public boolean createPdf(String filePath
                                    , List<String> header
                                    , List<List<String>> dataset
                                    , String title
                                    , int totalNumOfColumn){
    try
    {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(filePath));
        pdfDoc.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(
                new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));
        PdfDocumentInfo info = pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo();
        info.setAuthor("ABC");
        info.setCreator("ABC");
        info.setTitle(title);

        Document document = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4.rotate());
        Table table = new Table(totalNumOfColumn);

        // Adding header row
        for (String content : header){
            table.addHeaderCell(content);

        }

        // Adding data
        for (List<String> record : dataset) {
            for (String field : record) {
                table.addCell(field);
            }
        }
        document.add(table);
        document.close();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Please consider the code block where I am adding header row. If I modify the code to use little styling using `Cell` class as follows:

```
for (String content : header) {
    Cell cell = new Cell().setBold().add(content);
    table.addHeaderCell(cell);
}
```

Then my `document.add(table);` never returns.

I am not sure why. Please advise.

Comment: Something is wrong with setBold(). I tried Cell cell = new Cell().add(content); and it worked fine. But as soon as I add setBold(, it stopped working.

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example without any variables which are not known to the person who is trying to reproduce your problem? Also, which version are you using. I would also like to mention that `setBold()` is probably not the way you are looking at to make your text bold. You'd better try to fetch a real bold font and use it.